# Read specific part of json string with python

Tags: python, json, django, twitter, tweepy

I am currently working on a programme within the django environment which operates off a json api provided by a third party. There is an object within that API which I want however the string of information it provides is too much for me.

The data I want is the created_at tag from the twitter api using tweepy. This created_at contains data in the following format:

```
"created_at": "Mon Aug 27 17:21:03 +0000 2012"
```

This is all fine however this will return the date AND time whereas I simply want the the time part of the above example i.e. 17:21:03.

Is there any way I can just take this part of the created_at response string and store it in a separate variable?

Comment: use Regular Expressions..

Comment: @advay.umare could you elaborate?

Comment: m = re.findall(r'\d+:\d+:\d+',s)

Comment: Better use a proper datetime parser (builtin `datetime` module, `dateutil.parser`, `arrow` etc).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the **dateutil** module

```
from dateutil import parser

created_at = "Mon Aug 27 17:21:03 +0000 2012"
created_at = parser.parse(created_at)
print created_at.time()
```

**Output:**

```
17:21:03
```

Comment: When I print this I get the following message: AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @AdamDalton; That error looks unrelated to this solution.

Comment: Okay the issue there was I had not installed the dateutil in pip however now I receive the error message: TypeError: Parser must be a string or character stream, not datetime

Comment: I got it working by turning my variable into a string

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
my_datetime = response_from_twitter['created_at']
my_time = my_datetime.split(' ')[3]

# my_time will now contain time part.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string into a list and take the 4th element:

```
time = source['created_at'].split(' ')[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a regular expression with `re.search()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> d = {"created_at": "Mon Aug 27 17:21:03 +0000 2012"}
>>> re.search('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}', d['created_at']).group(0)
'17:21:03'
```